# c++ - How to get visible devices for Tensorflow?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am trying to fetch visible devices in Tensorflow C API. 
The following commands shows me `0` devices!

```
#include <tensorflow/core/public/session.h>
using namespace tensorflow;
...
tensorflow::SessionOptions tf_options;
std::cout << tf_options.config.device_count().size();
```

Does anyone knows how can I do it?